# How to match null passed to parameter of Class<T> with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have methods like these:

```
public <T> method(String s, Class<T> t) {...}
```

That I need to check that `null` is passed to the second argument when using matchers for the other parameters, I have been doing this :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
verify(client).method(eq("String"), any(Class.class));
```

But is there a better way (without suppress warnings) ? `T` represents the return type of some other method, which is sometimes `void` and in these cases `null` is passed in.

Comment: Have you tried `null` (instead of `any(Class.class)`)?

Comment: The problem is when your using matchers for the other parameters - you have to use matchers for all

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Update from David Wallace's answer:

As of 2016-12, Java 8 and Mockito 2.3,

```
public static <T> T isNull(Class<T> clazz)
```

is [Deprecated](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.3.10/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#isNull(java.lang.Class)) and will be removed in Mockito 3.0

use

```
public static <T> T isNull()
```

instead

Comment: This won't work 100%, I now need to cast the class, like so `(Integer) isNull()` instead of `isNull( Integer.class )`.

Comment: the syntax to avoid requiring a cast here is `org.mockito.Mockito.<String>isNull()`

Answer (score 144):

Mockito has an [`isNull` matcher](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Matchers.html#isNull(java.lang.Class)), where you can pass in the name of the class.  So if you need to use it with other matchers, the correct thing to do is

```
verify(client).method(eq("String"),isNull(Class<?>.class));
```

This is now deprecated, see the answer below for the new method - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41250852/1348

Comment: It should be noted that for strings you need to use `(String) isNull()`.

Comment: Yeah.  `isNull(String.class)` and `(String) isNull()` are equivalent.  Go with whichever makes more sense to you.

Comment: @mikerodent Thanks for the suggested edit.  You are absolutely right.  But you should probably post your suggestion as a new answer, rather than editing mine.  So I rejected your edit, even though I agree with it completely.

Comment: OK! Don't quite understand why, but I bow to your far superior knowledge of SO protocol!

Comment: I don't understand why either.  Surely an impending api change should be reflected somehow in this answer, nobody scrolls down :)

Answer (score 20):

This works for me:

```
verify(client).method(eq("String"), eq((Class<?>) null));
```

Comment: Thanks! I never think about casting null ... bye bye @SuppressWarnings